# How do i retrieve a particular instance of the same activity in the back stack?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity, A, instantiated 3 times for example (A1, A2, A3) in different parts of the back stack.

If my stack contains the following example: A1 -> B -> C -> A2 -> D -> A3 -> E, how can i specifically retrieve A1 or A2?

I am aware of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` but this only works well when there's only 1 instance of your Activity in your back stack. In my case it has only retrieved A3 when I've set this flag.

I am using the 2.3 SDK.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest: keep them separately in a Set (adding it in onCreate()/removing in onDestroy()). Really. You can keep reference to the set in Application .... Really.

Comment: Could you please further explain your solution with an example? I'm not entirely sure of your method.

Comment: Just to keep references in Java outside of the android activities... Have a Set<YourActivity> stored in Application (define your own application and add getActivitySet() method and store your activities there (it could be List or Stack as well - depends what you want). Then in onCreate() of your activity do ((YourApplication)getApplication()).getActivitySet().put(this) and remove in onDestroy.... that's about it.